# Magento user uploaded offers

Tags: magento, classification

Using Magento i want to create website where user can upload their products to sale, is it possible in magento ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create a website to handle that, Magento give you an API that you can easily consume for creating products, etc ...

> http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/introduction

But, why not just give your users an access to their webshop Administration area?

Answer (score 0):

Its better you to create module for add products by users from their my account area. Check the **saveAction** in **Mage/Adminhtml/Controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php** .You may get more idea how to save product.

If you are planning to add only some members to add their products through backend, its better you to create users and assign permissions to add products from backend.